# How do I use these variables outside of the function (python)?

Tags: python, function, class, variables, return

I've recently returned to Python programming and I have a question. In my code, I'm trying to set up slots but I can't figure out how to print them.

I have two files, Card and Main. This is the code for the Main file.

```
 
cardsList = ["dog", "fairy", "flower", 'ghost', "bow", "brain", "bird", "mountain", "glasses", "book", "water", "family", 'scream', "mask", "bacteria", "gun", "bomb", "motocycle"]

New = Card(cardsList)
New.Hand()
```

It's pretty self-explanatory for that one. This is the code for the Card file.

```
class Card(object):

  
  cardsList = list(["dog", "fairy", "flower", 'ghost', "bow", "brain", "bird", "mountain", "glasses", "book", "water", "family", 'scream', "mask", "bacteria", "gun", "bomb", "motocycle"])

  slot1 = ""
  slot2 = ""
  slot3 = ""
  slot4 = ""
  slot5 = ""
  slot6 = ""
  slot7 = ""
  slot8 = ""
  slot9 = ""
 
  

  def __init__(self, cardsList):
    self.cardsList = cardsList
    
   
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.cardsList)

  def Hand(cardsList):
    return len(cardsList)
    cardsList = random.shuffle(cardsList)
    listTwo = []
    for i in range(9):
      listTwo.append(cardsList[i])
      cardsList.pop(i)
    return listTwo
  
    
    
  slot1 = listTwo[1]
  slot2 = listTwo[2]
  slot3 = listTwo[3]
  slot4 = listTwo[4]
  slot5 = listTwo[5]
  slot6 = listTwo[6]
  slot7 = listTwo[7]
  slot8 = listTwo[8]
  slot9 = listTwo[9]

   
  slots = [slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7, slot8, slot9]
  print(slots)
```

Please let me know how to define the slot functions outside of the function. I need to use the slots for a different function, but I can't figure out how to get them working.

Comment: `slot1= ... slot2= ...` smells like you should have used a list.

Comment: I don't understand this code. Why do you define `cardsList` and `slot1` to `slot9` as class attributes? Then in `__init__` you define an additional `cardsList` on the instance. And even `print(slots)` is part of the `Card` definition. This is either a problem with your knowledge of object oriented programming or a screwed up indentation of the code.

Comment: What is the `Hand` function supposed to do? You `return` on the very first line but continue to add code after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
import random 

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, cardsList):
        self.cardsList = cardsList
        self.slot1 = ""
        self.slot2 = ""
        self.slot3 = ""
        self.slot4 = ""
        self.slot5 = ""
        self.slot6 = ""
        self.slot7 = ""
        self.slot8 = ""
        self.slot9 = ""
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cardsList)
    
    def Hand(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cardsList)
        self.slot1 = cardsList[0]
        self.slot2 = cardsList[1]
        self.slot3 = cardsList[2]
        self.slot4 = cardsList[3]
        self.slot5 = cardsList[4]
        self.slot6 = cardsList[5]
        self.slot7 = cardsList[6]
        self.slot8 = cardsList[7]
        self.slot9 = cardsList[8]

cardsList = ["dog", "fairy", "flower", 'ghost', "bow", "brain", "bird", "mountain", "glasses", "book", "water", "family", 'scream', "mask", "bacteria", "gun", "bomb", "motocycle"]
myCards = Card(cardsList)
myCards.Hand()
```

1. Creating an object of the class initializes all slots to "".
2. Calling the `Hand` function on the object assigns 9 random cards from cardsList to slots 1 through 9.

As an aside, `random.shuffle` shuffles the list *in place* so you should not be assigning this to anything.